# Make volume slider adjust only current program volume

Tags: windows, audio

Can I make The main Windows volume slider (or even a third party one if necessary) adjust only the current programs volume?

I currently use Eartrumpet but that sadly doesn't have that functionality.

Comment: The main windows volume slider is hard coded and already has a "sound mixer" option available via the context menu, so no, you cannot modify the main Windows volume slider to control a single application's volume. Whether there is another utility that does this is another question, the answer to which I do not know.

Comment: You can, but why do it? The app level can never exceed the master level. (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: @harrymc because I usually keep my master at 70 and adjust every other program separately, so I don't necessarily want to make them louder

Comment: In that case the task is impossible - we can't control this slider. You could instead opt for a script that increases/decreases the app volume by a given amount, but that's all I can think of.

Comment: @harrymc ok I'll look into it and thank you for taking the time to help me out

Comment: It's easy enough to write a AutoHotKey script for this, if you would you like an answer about it.